# How do I set region for BigQuery ML.FORECAST(?

Tags: google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

Using BigQuery ML in a local jupyter notebook (`%%bigquery`), I create a model in an EU dataset:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL mydataset.mymodel...
```

It evaluates fine:

```
ML.EVALUATE(MODEL mydataset.mymodel)...
```

but when I try to predict:

```
ML.FORECAST(MODEL mydataset.mymodel,...
```

I get:

```
Dataset myproject:mydataset was not found in location US
```

Why is `FORECAST` so xenophobic and how can I make it right?

Comment: You can specify the location in Bigquery. There is a button that says `MORE` there you select `Query Settings` at the bottom there is a dropdown button that lets you specify the Data Location.

Comment: Thanks this did indeed fix it so I can run it in BQ but I am trying to run it from a local jupyter notebook. I will edit qn to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of `%%bigquery` and instead used

`client = bigquery.Client(location=REGION)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. I guess your project path is missing.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL myproject.mydataset.mymodel...
ML.EVALUATE(MODEL myproject.mydataset.mymodel)...
ML.FORECAST(MODEL myproject.mydataset.mymodel,...
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but same error.